# Compiling libvorbis and libvorbisfile for Android

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, vorbis

I am porting a game using libvorbis and libvorbis file to Android. I have only been able to build libvorbis by running ndk-build on https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android. But my game also needs libvorbisfile which I cannot find any Android ports for.

How can I get libvorbisfile on Android ?

Comment: I downloaded the project and extracted it. Opened Android Studio (latest build with ndk support) and just imported the project. It required me to download build tools 23 which I did and everything seems to be working. All the libraries get rebuilt. Making use of it I will look further into tomorrow as I'm off out, but it hasn't flagged any problems so far.

Comment: Do you have libvorbisfile ?

Comment: I don't but it comes with the project as pre-built binaries with all the headers as well. It looks like a skeleton project that you can use that has everything with it. Or you can take out the libs and headers and add them to your own project using the skeleton as a guide to using it. I doubt very much I'll have time today as we are going to have a house full. I'll post back with what I find.

Comment: This may be of interest http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=451

Comment: @JonGoodwin My game is not a java one. It is a C/C++ game called SuperTuxKart

Comment: Are you asking for the libvorbis.so? If so, its here https://github.com/vincentjames501/libvorbis-libogg-android/tree/master/libs

Comment: @NickIsaacs No , i need libvorbisfile.so